# Meaning in car/wiring context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Whenever I try to use any available translator I've got strange results like 
"special for free light".

16款自由光专用
What can this sentence mean in car or electric wiring context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'For use in a '16 Cherokee'

款 referring to the model type/year (2016)

自由光 being the model (Jeep Cherokee)

专用 Exclusive use / Dedicated